# How to extract the data in between 2 header tags?

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, text-extraction, data-extraction

I'm working on scraping the website and I want to extract the data in between the 2 headers and tag it to first tag as key-value pair.

How to extract the text under headers (like h1 and h2) ?

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
items = soup.select("div.conWrap")

htag_count = []
item_header = soup.find_all(re.compile('^h[1-6]'))
for item in item_header:
    htag_count.append({item.name:item.text})

print(htag_count)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample of HTML and what info exactly you want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work if the `h_` tags don't share a direct [parent](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parent) , but you could try looping through [sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) tags after each `h_` tag [and stop if the next `h_` tag is reached].

```py
# url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Yonge' [ for example ]
# soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)

# item_header = soup.find_all(re.compile('^h[1-6]')) # should be same as
item_header = soup.find_all([f'h{i}' for i in range(1,7)])

skipTags = ['script', 'style'] # any tags you don't want text from
hSections = []

for h in item_header:
    sectionLines = []

    for ns in  h.find_next_siblings():
        if ns in item_header: break # stop if/when next header is reached
        if ns.name in skipTags: continue # skip certain tags

        sectionLines.append(' '.join(ns.get_text(' ').split())) 
        # [ split+join to minimize whitespace ] 

    hSections.append({
        'header_type': h.name, 'header_text': h.get_text(' ').strip(),
        'section_text': '\n'.join([l for l in sectionLines if l])
    })
```

---

I couldn't test this properly since you didn't include any html snippet nor a link to the site you want to scrape, but when tried on a Wikipedia page, `hSections` (after truncating and tabulating) looks like: [image: sampop]

<sub>You can also take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75263236/6146136) if you're interested in nesting subsection into the parent sections.</sub>

Comment: Got it! I could modify this as per my requirement. 
Thank you :)