# python: how to scrape title and respective texts one after the other

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

I am using python and beautiful soup to scrape the following page:

```
url = "https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/13-anti-inflammatory-foods"

# Send an HTTP request to the URL and get the HTML content
response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.text

# Parse the HTML content with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Find all anchor tags <a> and paragraph tags <p> on the page
anchor_tags = soup.find_all('a')
paragraph_tags = soup.find_all('p')

# Function to recursively extract text from a tag with nested tags
def extract_tag_text(tag):
    tag_text = ""
    for element in tag.contents:
        if isinstance(element, str):  # If the element is a string, add it to the text
            tag_text += element
        else:  # Recursively extract text from nested tags
            tag_text += extract_tag_text(element)
    return tag_text.strip()

# Initialize a list to store the extracted text from 'a' and 'p' tags
extracted_text = []

# Extract text from 'a' tags
for anchor_tag in anchor_tags:
    anchor_text = extract_tag_text(anchor_tag)
    if anchor_text.strip():
        extracted_text.append(anchor_text)

# Extract text from 'p' tags
for paragraph_tag in paragraph_tags:
    paragraph_text = extract_tag_text(paragraph_tag)
    if paragraph_text.strip():
        extracted_text.append(paragraph_text)

# Combine the extracted text into a single string
all_text = "\n".join(extracted_text)

# Print the extracted text
print(all_text)
```

while the above code that I have written gives me the text in this page, i would like to correctly match each header with its respective text. and the list to appear as a list and if there is no header, then just the text.

Comment: Are you looking for [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75202810/6146136)? Btw, your `extract_tag_text` doesn't look too different from [`.get-text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)....